# How to generate keywords from string with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to generate all possible keywords from string

For example, my string is:

```
mystring = "IPHONE X FOR SELL";
```

I checked splice and I got part of what I need

```
array = mystring.split(" ");
//output [ "IPHONE", "X", "FOR", "SELL" ]
```

So how can I make output like the bellow array ?

```
[ IPHONE, X, FOR, SELL, IPHONE X, X FOR, FOR SELL, IPHONE X FOR, X FOR SELL, IPHONE X FOR SELL ]
```

Comment: Why did you think that [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) would give you all possible combinations?

Comment: splice gave me part of need. but i don't know how to get the other possible keywords if i have multiple words

Comment: This is just a matter of generating all possible combinations from the array while preserving word order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const string = "IPHONE X FOR SELL";

const items = string.split(' ');

const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    for (let j = 1; j <= items.length; j++) {

        const slice = items.slice(i,j);

        if (slice.length)
            result.push(slice.join(' '));
    }

}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great... yes that what i need. Thank u so much Alizadeh